# Can you add optional _outer_ tags in svelte conditional statement?

Tags: svelte

Is it possible to use a conditional statement to wrap inner content with an optional outer element?

Here is an example of what I want to do in valid Svelte:

```
<script>
  export let needs_div_wrapper;
</script>

{#if needs_div_wrapper}
  <div>
    <a>My static content!</a>
  </div>
{:else}
  <a>My static content!</a>
{/if}
```

And here is an example in non-valid Svelte that demonstrates what I want to do:

```
...

{#if needs_div_wrapper}
  <div>
{/if}
    <a>My static content!</a>
{#if needs_div_wrapper}
  </div>
{/if}
```

EDIT: Just for clarity, I'm trying to accomplish this *without* a new component for the inner content.

Comment: I would like something like this too. I created an issue on the Svelte GitHub: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/7528

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

A wrapper component is probably the cleanest you can do in this case, to avoid repeating potentially non trivial markup in the "parent" component.

As I understand it, you've already found this solution, but for the record here's what I mean:

`DivWrapper.svelte`

```html
<script>
  export let wrap = false
</script>
{#if wrap}
  <div {...$$restProps}>
    <slot />
  </div>
{:else}
  <slot />
{/if}
```

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
  import DivWrapper from './DivWrapper.svelte'

  export let needs_div_wrapper;
</script>

<DivWrapper wrap={needs_div_wrapper}>
  <a>My static content!</a>
</DivWrapper>
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but still relevant I guess. I've come up with this solution, works at least for some use cases:

```html
<script>
  export let needs_div_wrapper;
</script>

<div class="{ needs_div_wrapper ? '' : 'contents'}">
  <a>My static content!</a>
</div>

<style>
.contents { display: contents; }
</style>
```

Comment: I originally asked this question generally, and the lack of a general answer played a role in my understanding of the limits of svelte. 

I didn't know about display: contents. That's going to be useful.

As far as conditional classes go, I like this syntax:

```
<script>
  export let needs_div_wrapper;
</script>

<div class:contents={needs_div_wrapper}>
  <a>My static content!</a>
</div>

<style>
.contents { display: contents; }
</style>
```